# Linux Kernel should I use asmlinkage for a function that implements a system call?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, system-calls, calling-convention

I am trying to implement a new syscall in linux kernel, so I wrote:

```
asmlinkage int my_func(void) {
    return my_func_internal();
}
```

my question, should I define `my_func_internal` as `asmlinkage` or not?

In other words, should I write A or B?

A) `asmlinkage int my_func_internal(void) {return 1;}`

B) `int my_func_internal(void) {return 1;}`

I would like some explanation too

**Note:** I have added `my_func` to `syscalls.h` should I add the internal one too (probably the answer is no)

Comment: Rather than declaring the syscall functions directly with `asmlinkage`, you should be using the `SYSCALL_DEFINE` macros, e.g. `SYSCALL_DEFINE0(my_func)` `{` `return my_func_internal();` `}`. That is needed for compatibility with architectures that use syscall wrappers. Note: the macro will set the name of the function to `sys_my_func` unless it uses syscall wrappers, in which case the name will be something else ending in `_my_func`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter (for correctness) what calling convention you use for functions that aren't called *directly* by hand-written asm.  (Which syscall implementation functions might be on some architectures, that's why they should be `asmlinkage`.)  As long as all callers can see a prototype that matches the definition, it will work.

If `asmlinkinkage` is a different calling convention from the default one (e.g. on i386, `asmlinkage` means to use stack args, overriding the `-mregparm=3` build option that makes internal functions use register args), the compiler will have to emit a definition for `my_func` that handles the difference if it calls a function that isn't `asmlinkage`.  Or simply inline `my_func_internal()` into it.

If they use the same calling convention, and the compiler chooses not to inline, it could just do an optimized tailcall to `my_func_internal`, e.g. on x86 `jmp my_func_internal`.  So there's a possible efficiency advantage to using the same calling convention *if* there's a possibility of an optimized tailcall.  Otherwise don't; `asmlinkage` makes the calling convention less efficient on i386.

(IIRC, `asmlinkage` has no effect on x86-64 and most other modern ISAs with register-args calling conventions; the default calling convention on x86 is already good so the kernel doesn't need to override it with `-mregparm=3` like it does on i386.)

**In your example where there are no args, there's no difference.**

---

BTW, the usual naming convention for the function name is `sys_foo` to implement a system-call called `foo`.  i.e. the function that will get called when user-space passes `__NR_foo` as the call number.

---

> Note: I have added my_func to syscalls.h should I add the internal one too (probably the answer is no)

Of course not, unless `my_func_internal` implements a *different* system call that you want user-space to be able to call directly.

Comment: So to be on the safe side I should add "asmlinkage" in case I don't care about performance? (can't I type inline instead or that's wrong, forgot to mention my_func_internal is recursive function)

Comment: @mr_calc: No, there's no correctness reason at all to use `asmlinkage` on `foo_internal`.   Unless you add it to the system-call table so it can be called *directly* by user-space, implementing a different system call.  Assuming you don't want to do that, use`static foo_internal` if possible to encourage the compiler to inline, especially if there's only one caller.

Comment: so could you write a final suggestion, you mentioned a lot of things here static and not static. yes this is the only way I am calling the internal function, it's called one time only by my_func

Comment: @mr_calc: I was assuming you understood what `static` means in normal C, and that you generally want to use it for functions when possible (i.e. to make them only visible inside a single file).  So yes, in your case, make it `static int foo_internal(void)`.